# Understanding ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms

Tags: ssh, macos, aws, openssh

I am having problem in connecting to an Amazon EC2 Linux instance from an old Mac OS machine running El Capitan. Unfortunately without any possibility to upgrade the OS.

Because all the other modern devices I have can connect to the instance without any problems using the same key, I suppose the problem is related to the way the ssh client interact with the server, in particular due to old ssh client version.

The private key has been generated by the EC2 console.

So I went for a little debugging on the server side and found this message:

```
userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

Then I have analyzed the authorized_keys file on server side and found this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa <long string> mykey-rsa
```

For start, I was wondering why if the key is marked as ssh-rsa the server is instead refusing such option.

So I ssh to the machine with -vvv option to get this fragment from the output:

```
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    ....
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
```

If I am not wrong the entries in the first part are the options from client side, while the others are from server side. Infact I can see that the ssh-rsa is only available on client side. So I tought that choosing one common algoritm would have solved the issue:

```
ssh -l ec2-user myserver -i .ssh/ec2-key.pem  -vvvvvv -oKexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

but again I am seeing the same error on server side:

```
userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

what am I missing ?

I know that I could solve the problem by authorizing ssh-rsa on server side, but I am more interested in understanding what's going on.

**[UPDATE]**

Following the suggested approaches (which I have marked as accepted), I went for option 2, as it is not easy and probably dangerous to upgrade an old MacOS at such code level.

EC2 Key Pair console gives two options RSA and ED25519, I choosed a key with 'ED25519' and replaced the related public key on the authorized keys file and I can now connect to the instance.

Comment: Note that first the client and server do key exchange to create a secure tunnel between the client and the server.  Then, the client authenticates with the server using public key based authentication.  It looks like the first step completes successfully, but the problem is in the second step, and the error that you are seeing pertains to the second step.  In your sshd_config on the server, what do you have for `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`?

Comment: Note that the server is complaining about `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` (i. e. the signature algorithm), not `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` (the SSH key type). Servers which ban RSA keys and only allow ECDSA/EdDSA should be rare, and this would pop up in the error log first, I believe.

Comment: Both Homebrew and MacPorts have OpenSSH 9.3p1. It’s probably a good idea to install this and use it instead of the Apple provided old version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name `ssh-rsa` has two different meanings here.

There's the *key type* `ssh-rsa` which you can see in the first column of your `authorized_keys`file. RSA keys are perfectly fine and widely supported.

However, there's also the *signature* algorithm `ssh-rsa` which stands for RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm. Since SHA-1 is insecure, [OpenSSH disables the `ssh-rsa` signature algorithm since version 8.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8). SSH clients and servers are now expected to use `rsa-sha2-256` (RSA signatures with SHA-256) or `rsa-sha2-512` (RSA signatures with SHA-512).

To fix the problem, there are three options:

- Update the SSH client, so that the newer signature algorithms can be used. This is by far the best solution. If you cannot get a current OpenSSH version through your OS, then install OpenSSH independently.
- Create a new SSH key with the ECDSA type (e. g. `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`) or EdDSA rather than RSA. Then you can circumvent the signature algorithm problem.
- If, for some strange reason, you cannot do either, then the last resort is to enable the `ssh-rsa` signature algorithm on the server by adding it to `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`. Note that this is a security risk.

Comment: I have searched a lot about 'easily' upgrading the openssh client, but found nothing. You are telling me that I can install openssh independently ? Even If I have solved the problem with option two, can you give me more information about it ?

Comment: You could install the [portable release of OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) by compiling the source code. This should run fine on older macOS versions.

Comment: Thank you, a new key generated using "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa" worked perfectly